# Comparing quantitative data from a variety of tests

Tags: distributions, t-test, normalization, z-score

I have a data set comprising about 20 track and fields events, each with about 50 data points from males and 50 from females. Those I've checked so far are normal distributions (within sex).

My null is that there is no performance difference between male and female athletes.

Is there a way I can transform data across the different events to effectively normalise the different metrics? I obviously can't normalise a race time and a height jumped. I can't even transform race times to velocity, because different distances are run at different (and variable) velocities.

I can find the mean/SD (males plus females) for each event and z score every individual performance. I end up with a ton of male performances that are negative and a ton of female performances that are positive. Where can I go from here?

Should I just z-test/t-test each event and present a list of events? That seems a little underwhelming :)

(Not an expert so any explanations will have to be simple)